# standard deviation VS variance

Tags: variance, standard-deviation

Problem statment:
What is the different between standard deviation and variance? 
What context should it be used for both of them?

Comment: What's the difference between the side of a square and its area?

Answer (score 2):

standard deviation = square root of variance, hence standard deviation is usually written as $\sigma$ and variance as $\sigma^2$.

[Here](http://www.mathsisfun.com/data/standard-deviation.html)'s a basic explanation comparing the two and how they can be used in basic situations.

In more complicated statistics, variance is used in a lot of ways, such as amount of variance explained (like to calculate $R^2$ or the Intra-Class Correlation coefficient (ICC), which is the amount of variance explained by each level in a multi-level experiment or model.